# Failed to load plugin libgazebo...: libgazebo...: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, gazebo, linux

When running a command similar to the `roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch` of the [Tutorial: Using roslaunch to start Gazebo, world files and URDF models](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch), I get the following error:

> [Err] [Plugin.hh:180] Failed to load plugin libgazebo[...]:
> libgazebo[...]: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to remove the catkin workspace and install it again.

Remove:
In your catkin workspace, usually your project folder, delete (or rename with suffix "_old" if you want to compare the not working catkin workspace later with the working catkin workspace):

- build
- devel
- optionally src/CMakeLists.txt (I did that, not sure if it is really needed)

Source:
[Removing catkin workspace](https://answers.ros.org/question/66012/removing-catkin-workspace/?answer=66014#post-id-66014)

Afterwards, the fresh `catkin_make -j8` (or whatever catkin command you use) in my catkin workspace in the Python base environment installed without errors and the `roslaunch` command ran through.